# What is the best way to convert from a C++ std::vector<float> to a Rust Vec<f32>?

Tags: c++, rust

I wrote a test program to check that the data will be read correctly on the Rust.

C++ code:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.push_back(10);
vec.push_back(20);
std::cout << "len is " << get_len(&vec);
```

Rust code:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_len(vec: *const Vec<f32>) -> i32 {
    let vec= unsafe { &*vec};
    vec.len() as i32
}
```

My output looks like this and is always different:

```
len is 603268424
```

Comment: C++'s `std::vector<T>` has no guarantees on layout (it's very likely to be different across standard library implementations). You need to reduce it to something that both languages can understand, possibly something like passing `vec.data()` and `vec.size()` separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing to know is that C++ doesn't allow giving away the ownership of the data vector. This is a limitation of the C++ design. There are some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123022/preventing-a-destructor-from-running-in-c#9123068) but I don't advise using them. To stay "safe", you can only borrow a C++ vector.

This can be done easily, using [`vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) and [`vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

extern "C" void show_vector(float const *data, std::size_t size);

int main() {
    std::vector<float> vec{10, 20};
    show_vector(vec.data(), vec.size());
}
```

The Rust side can use [`slice::from_raw_parts()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html), creating a view of our vector without taking ownership.

```rust
use libc::{c_float, size_t};

extern "C" fn show_vector(data: *const c_float, size: size_t) {
    let vec = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(data, size) };
    for x in vec {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Read more:

- [Can I call C or C++ functions from Rust code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105186/can-i-call-c-or-c-functions-from-rust-code/50230460#50230460)
- [How can I get an array or a slice from a raw pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150652/how-can-i-get-an-array-or-a-slice-from-a-raw-pointer)

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! Also working with `std::vector<struct my_struct>` -> `Vec<MyStruct>`!
Very helpful!

Comment: @ArtemKolokoltsev Be sure to at least use [`#[repr(C)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprc) on Rust side, it's not perfect but better than nothing, be aware that you could run into problem if you are not extra careful with data representation. "We strongly recommend using rust-bindgen and/or cbindgen to manage your FFI boundaries for you."